# How to record microphone audio in Planetside 2 Twitch streaming?

Tags: planetside-2, streaming

It's easy enough to set up Planetside 2 to record gameplay for Twitch streaming (since it's built-in), but I want it to record my voice commentary from my headset microphone as well.  It doesn't seem to do this by default, though.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using a separate program? A quick search came up with a few things, but I'm not a streamer so I wouldn't know if they're useful or not. Probably not...

Comment: So is it already streaming you commentary and you just want to record it locally for later, or are you having trouble streaming your voice?

Comment: @MBraedley It's not already streaming commentary; I want it to but I don't know how to get it to record my voice for commentary *through the game*.

I haven't tried another program yet, and I assume that will work, but I was hoping it was supported natively through the game's Twitch streaming support.

Comment: I thought that was the case.  Is there a built in voice chat system?  I'm thinking the controls for streaming would be in a similar place.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to employ a program that can create a virtual audio card that mixes in both devices (outputs) into one which can then be streamed out.

The program I would recommend is Virtual Audio Cable (VAC). Setting it up may take a bit of reading, but this is what you need to do to get it up and running. I'm certain there are many guides for it!

Good Luck!